# Upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10, and now my mouse and keyboard are so laggy it's almsot unsuable

Tags: drivers, 20.04, keyboard, mouse, 21.10

I just upgraded my system as my OS asked me if I wanted to. Ubuntu 20.04 ran super smooth and I had little to no issues with it. Now since I upgraded, the mouse and keyboard slow down more and more after the PC has been running for a little bit . It's so bad right now I am having issues with typos. The mouse lags like crazy too. I am really frustrated, I have work to do!

I have an RX 580 GPU with the latest driver https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580.

What's weird too is just as a I switched the page and came back to this one, it's far less laggy now. I have no clue what's going on. What can I do to fix this? If I can't fix it, how can I downgrade? I really don't want to lose all my stuff, and I really don't want to re install the entire OS!

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Did you also apply latest updates / patches ? `sudo apt update` and `sudio apt upgrade` and a `reboot.

Comment: Everything is upgraded and updated. I have rebooted multiple times, it works fine after reboot. Once my screen goes on lock and I unlock it, the mouse and keyboard are laggy again. This is so laggy it's unusable, I'm probably going to have to reboot again just so I can get back to work

Comment: Can you check ram usage by opening `system monitor`? In case the RAM usage is high, can you check which process is consuming so much RAM? Sometimes, the mouse cursor lags when not much RAM is available. This might be caused by some sort of memory leak.

Comment: Please report mouse/keyboard lag when using Wayland to the developers via a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

Did you may be previously run under Xorg and now you were silently transferred to Wayland?  In the login screen, you should be able to select "Ubuntu on Xorg" instead of "Ubuntu".

Comment: How can I check if the Gnome shell extensions are up to date or not and are running error logs? I will try out the the x11 on the login screen! I did not see an x11 as an option, there was only ubuntu and xorg. I switched to xorg this is definitely not the same setup I had previously. Will have to wait and see if it bugs

Comment: xorg is X11, sorry.  About the extensions: I would switch them all off, then activate one by one and watch how it goes.

Comment: I could not create a comment because I am a new user, do you suggest to hold back in this case?

Comment: It looks like switching xorg solved the problem!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear. There are a few other things that seem to work flawlessly with Xorg but not at all with Wayland (e.g. tiling window extensions, Zoom screen sharing, various presentation modes in other software ...), and I find it irritating that Ubuntu keeps defaulting to Wayland with each recent upgrade. If you think this is good enough as an answer, could you please accept it as the solution to the problem? That would count up our respective credentials and may be we can soon comment on questions (as requested earlier ;)).

Comment: @axtimwalde Never mind the comment thing. You are not supposed to ask a question in an answer (something like "Does updating extensions solve the issue?"). But now that it fixes the issue, it is a great answer. Also, I have removed the extension part from the answer, as it turned out to be not relevant to this question.

Comment: @SamWinstead About accepting answers. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/281134